# A function with a template in its argument throws an error when called with an int

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to implement my own versioin of std::vector for practice. This is my first time working with templates so it's possible the solution is trivial but I have not been able to find anything on Google. The vector class I created has a template T which is supposed to be the variable type the vector is storing. In the push_back() function I am using "T value" as the argument. If I understand correctly that should make the function able to use whatever value the vector is initialized to store as the argument.

In main I am calling myvector.push_back(100) and getting the following error:

```
no instance of function template "myVector<T>::push_back [with T=int]" matches the argument listC/C++(304)
CustomContainer.cpp(112, 13): argument types are: (int)
CustomContainer.cpp(112, 13): object type is: myVector<int>
```

as well as:

"no matching function for call to 'myVector::push_back(int)'".

Here is my code:

```
template <typename T> 
class myVector
{
    private:
        int my_size = 0;
        int capacity = 1;
        T* arr;

    public:
        myVector() 
        {
            my_size = 0;
            capacity = 1;
            arr = new T[1];
        }

        myVector(unsigned int new_cap)
        {
            capacity = new_cap;
            arr = new T[new_cap];
        }

        myVector(unsigned int new_cap, T content)
        {
            capacity = new_cap;
            arr = new T[new_cap];
            std::fill_n(*arr, new_cap, content);
        }

        ~ myVector()
        {
            delete[] arr;
        }

        template <typename C>
        void push_back(T value)
        {
            if(my_size < capacity)
            {
                capacity = ceil((double)capacity * 1.5);
                C* temp = new C[capacity];
                std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::begin(temp));
                delete arr;
                arr = temp;
                temp = NULL;
                my_size++;
            }
            arr[my_size++] = value;
        }

//more methods here, none of which are named "push_back"
};

int main()
{
    myVector<int> poggers;
    poggers.push_back(100);
}
```

I have tried creating the following function:

```
void push_back(int value)
{

}
```

and it made the error go away so it looks to me like a templates issue.

Any class design critique is also welcome.

Comment: `void push_back(T value)`: <- This is what you need. Just get rid of the `C` from everywhere in that method implementation and replace with `T`.

Comment: Why have you declared `push_back` with a template?

Comment: You should be using member initialization lists in your constructors. E.g. `myVector() : my_size(0), capacity(1), arr(new T[1]) {}`

Comment: Also wouldn't be a bad idea to implement copy and move constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: also consider replacinh `C* temp = new C[capacity];` with `auto temp = std::make_unique<C[]>(capacity)` and your swap code with `arr.reset(temp);`. In general try to avoid naked new/deletes as much as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is generally broken. You should not be using a distinct template parameter type `C`, when the class itself stores type `T`. Otherwise you'll get type mismatches when you allocate a new array of `C`.

You were also using the wrong `delete` in that function, and `std::begin` / `std::end` don't work for raw pointers. Just use the pointers themselves, as they are compatible with iterators.

It's also not a great idea to use floating point arithmetic for the expansion. You can use integers instead. Although it's a bit fiddly due to your initial size of 1, you can handle the size-1 edge case by adding 1 and avoiding any branching:

```
capacity += (capacity + 1) / 2;
```

Also made the argument a reference instead of copy, and removed a double size increase.

The not-large-enough test was backwards. You need `my_size == capacity`. More "accident-proof" to use `my_size >= capacity`, I think, but watch out for future logic if you're pushing multiple values at once. You'll need to ensure that you select a large enough size.

```
void push_back(const T& value)
{
    if(my_size >= capacity)
    {
        capacity += (capacity + 1) / 2;
        T* temp = new T[capacity];
        std::copy(arr, arr + my_size, temp);
        delete[] arr;
        arr = temp;
    }
    arr[my_size++] = value;
}
```

Note that it's probably not a good idea to use `int` for the sizes. Containers use an unsigned type, and usually `std::size_t`. You may want to add safety by ensuring you do not overflow your capacity when enlarging the vector.

Because you have a non-trivial class with raw memory management, you'll need copy constructor / copy-assignment. See [What is the Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1553090)

Consider also supporting move-semantics. Not only for `push_back` (avoiding the copy of non-trivial types that you may want to store in the vector) but more generally for your move-construction / move-assignment.

Instead of managing raw pointers, it would be cleaner to use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback, it is much appreciated. Your points make a lot of sense. I wanted to clarify what you mean by "move semantics". Also, what does changing the argument from copy to reference do?

Comment: @Shadows_Puppet, refer to [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for the reason of implementing move sementics.

Comment: Regarding the reference, it's just more correct. It guarantees there won't be an additional copy when passing a value to the function. If you're storing integers, that's trivial, but if your vector stores `myVector<int>` values, a copy would be heavy. To completely avoid the copy (when assigning the value to the vector itself), use move-semantics, which allows you to transfer ownership.

Comment: @paddy Thank you! I'm using raw pointers to practice memory management, is it still better to use smart pointers?

Comment: It's fine to practice and learn how to manage memory, but you'll likely find that smart pointers are just better in most cases.